# Decoding golang http.Client POST output

Tags: json, go, https

I am trying to learn golang and I am trying to "port" an old PHP script to golang.
Now I am having a question regarding "decoding" the body of a http.Client POST request.
(I am probably to old to learn a new language...)

My code looks like this (shortened):

```
var my_client = &http.Client{
    Transport: my_Trans,        // Defined elsewhere
    Timeout:   my_TimeOut,      // Defined elsewhere
}
logininfo := map[string]interface{}{"username": user, "password": pw}
payload, _ := json.Marshal(logininfo)
request, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://abc.def.com", bytes.NewBuffer(payload))
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
response, err := my_client.Do(request)
defer response.Body.Close()
log.Printf("response.Body")
log.Printf("%s", response.Body)
```

This outputs the body of the response which looks likes this:

```
2021/01/13 13:50:31 response.Body
2021/01/13 13:50:31 {{"data":{"state":1,"id":"1234567890","Token":"ABCDEF0123456","lastloginip":"192.168.10.1","lastlogintime":1600000000},"error":{"code":0,"description":"0"}}
}
```

From that body I would like to extract the two fields "id" and "Token".
What I have come up with is the following:

```
type my_loginResult struct {
    Data struct {
        State         int    `json:"state"`
        Id            string `json:"id"`
        Token         string `json:"Token"`
        Lastloginip   string `json:"lastloginip"`
        Lastlogintime int    `json:"lastlogintime"`
    }
    Error struct {
        Code        int    `json:"code"`
        Description string `json:"description"`
    }
}

resultjson := my_loginResult{}
tmp_body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
json.Unmarshal(tmp_body, &resultjson)
id = resultjson.Data.Id
token = resultjson.Data.Token
```

Is this the "correct" and most efficient way to "decode" the body?

In PHP I can just do:

```
id = $response->body->data->id;
token = $response->body->data->Token;
```

Regards,

Dan

Comment: Looks fine to me, what problem are you having with it?

Comment: Note though that Go style prefers pascalCase over snake_case for names.

Comment: if this is you input json, then it is not valid: `{{"data":{"state":1,"id":"1234567890","Token":"ABCDEF0123456","lastloginip":"192.168.10.1","lastlogintime":1600000000},"error":{"code":0,"description":"0"}}}`.  What exactly is your input json?

Comment: Note, that you are ignoring the error returned from `json.Unmarshal`. Check the error, always! It would have told you about the invalid json.

Comment: @D.M.J. Try something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/KUJrw9YPW2o -- 1. Don't ignore errors. 2. Specifying only those fields that you need is ok. 3. If your json is behind an `io.Reader` you can use `json.Decoder`, it is supposed to be more efficient for decoding streams of json.

Comment: @Adrian: The code works, I was just wondering if there are some improvements I can make or if I have over-complicated it and there is a "smarter" way. I'll keep the "variable-style" in mind in the future.

Comment: @TehSphinX: That is the output from "log.Printf("%s", response.Body)" and as I said, my code is Working so the json seems to be OK. The code I posted is just a quick "mockup", in the final code I will include error checking.

Comment: @mkopriva: I will look into this - thx. for the tipp.

Comment: @D.M.J. StackOverflow is for specific questions/problems, if you're looking for a code review head over to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think your solution should work. Are you facing any issue. Also you can also use map instead of struct. But that will add complexity.

Comment: The code-snippet from "play.golang.org/p/KUJrw9YPW2o" did tidy up my code somewhat and works like a charm.

Thanks a lot!